# Programmatically read the last 10 records from HBase via Thrift call

Tags: node.js, hbase, thrift

In hbase shell I can

```
scan 't1', { LIMIT=>10, REVERSED => TRUE}
```

and I can see the last 10 records loaded into table
When I try the logically same function in node.js via thrift the returned results are the first 10

```
thrift logs at trace level 
2014-12-30 21:23:31,652 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner: Scan table=t1, startRow=000000030000
2014-12-30 21:23:31,652 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for service ClientService, sasl=false
2014-12-30 21:23:31,652 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: Connecting to hdpnode1/127.0.0.1:60020
2014-12-30 21:23:31,653 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: IPC Client (2037671159) connection to hdpnode1/127.0.0.1:60020 from hbase: starting, connections 1
2014-12-30 21:23:31,653 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: IPC Client (2037671159) connection to hdpnode1/127.0.0.1:60020 from hbase: wrote request header call_id: 45 method_name: "Scan" request_param: true
2014-12-30 21:23:31,654 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: IPC Client (2037671159) connection to hdpnode1/127.0.0.1:60020 from hbase: got response header call_id: 45, totalSize: 14 bytes
2014-12-30 21:23:31,654 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: Call: Scan, callTime: 2ms
2014-12-30 21:23:31,736 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.thrift.ThriftServerRunner$HBaseHandler: scannerGetList: id=23
2014-12-30 21:23:31,737 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: IPC Client (2037671159) connection to hdpnode1/127.0.0.1:60020 from hbase: wrote request header call_id: 46 method_name: "Scan" request_param: true
2014-12-30 21:23:31,738 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: IPC Client (2037671159) connection to hdpnode1/127.0.0.1:60020 from hbase: got response header call_id: 46 cell_block_meta { length: 47600 }, totalSize: 47821 bytes
2014-12-30 21:23:31,738 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: Call: Scan, callTime: 2ms
2014-12-30 21:23:41,737 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: IPC Client (2037671159) connection to hdpnode1/127.0.0.1:60020 from hbase: closed
2014-12-30 21:23:41,737 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcClient: IPC Client (2037671159) connection to hdpnode1/127.0.0.1:60020 from hbase: stopped, connections 0
```

Questions are

1. how can I tell that I am passing the correct parameter to thrift
2. does thrift-nodejs support it

I am on

- CDH 5.3
- hbase 0.98.6

I am trying to leverge the reversed option in a scan via thrift (node.js to be specific)

Thrift set to hsha and per CM it should be framed nodejs compiled from https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs

Comment: You should try to improve the quality of your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "*When I try the logically same function in node.js via thrift*" - Just where it starts to become interesting, that part is missing. Could you add that piece of the puzzle?

Comment: /* thrift 1 */
self.hbase.scannerOpenWithScan(table, scan, null, function(err, id) {
  console.log(err, id);
  
  self.hbase.scannerGetList(id, count, function (err, rows){
    console.log(err, rows);
  });
});

/* thrift 2 */
self.hbase.openScanner(table, scan, function(err, id) {
  console.log(err, id);     
  
  self.hbase.getScannerRows(id, count, function (err, rows){
    console.log(err, rows);
  });
});

Comment: Reverse scan is a "pretty new" feature (and it's also up to 40% slower), It doesn't seem to be supported by the HBase thrift API. Perhaps you could fall back to the previous way of doing reverses: storing the same data in 2 tables (with ascending and descending row keys).